# MAX query problems

Tags: sql, ms-access, max

I'm working on an assignment and I have a table with several columns. The two I'm interested in are the `Type` and the `Easting` column.

I'm trying to use a query to return the max value from the `Easting` column and also show me what that value holds in the `Type` column.

I'm using Microsoft Access for the assignment.

Here is what I have so far, but it returns all the values not the max

```
SELECT Type, Location,MAX(Easting)
FROM CrimeData
GROUP BY Easting, Location, Type
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: remove `Easting` from the group by list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to obtain the maximum `Easting` value (using a subquery), and then select all records which hold such value, e.g.:

```
select c.type, c.location, c.easting
from crimedata c
where c.easting = (select max(t.easting) from crimedata t)
```

Solutions which use a `group by` clause will only provide the maximum `Easting` value for records within each combination of values held by the fields in the `group by` clause.

Comment: thats perfect very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You must group by all output columns except the one with the aggregate (MAX).

```
SELECT Type, Location, MAX(Easting)
FROM CrimeData
GROUP BY Type, Location
```

When you are grouping, you can filter the raw data before grouping with a WHERE clause and the grouped data after grouping with a having clause. e.g.

```
SELECT Type, Location, MAX(Easting)
FROM CrimeData
WHERE Type > 1
GROUP BY Type, Location
HAVING MAX(Easting) < 10
```

Comment: oh that simple lol, well thats narrowed it down to 11 but still includes a few that are below the max value

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Type, Location, MAX(Easting)
FROM CrimeData
GROUP BY Location, Type
HAVING Easting = MAX(Easting)
```

or simpler:

```
SELECT Type, Location, Easting
FROM CrimeData
where Easting = (select max(Easting) from CrimeData)
```

The column you use in the function (in your case MAX) should not be part of the group by statement.
Hopefully this clears it otherwise I can explain more ;)

Comment: yes ive just tried that but maybe i didnt explain myself enough in the initial post this gives me the max value for every location, but im looking to only include the MAX number period and show the location and type for that value if that makes sense?